# 'Import Error: No module named msvc' when running pip install ipdb on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python-2.7, pip, ubuntu-18.04

I keep getting this error when trying to run pip install ipdb on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
Collecting ipdb
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/df/78/3d0d7253dc85549db182cbe4b43b30c506c84008fcd39898122c9b6306a9/ipdb-0.12.2.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-PpJ5WV/ipdb/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-PpJ5WV/ipdb/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-PpJ5WV/ipdb/
    Complete output (11 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/opt/symphony-client/setuptools/__init__.py", line 160, in <module>
        monkey.patch_all()
      File "/opt/symphony-client/setuptools/monkey.py", line 104, in patch_all
        patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler()
      File "/opt/symphony-client/setuptools/monkey.py", line 156, in patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler
        msvc = import_module('setuptools.msvc')
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
        __import__(name)
    ImportError: No module named msvc
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I did a pip search msvc and it found msvc-runtime but when I try and pip install msvc-runtime I get the following:

```
Collecting msvc-runtime
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement msvc-runtime (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for msvc-runtime
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your `/usr/bin/python` seems to be imorting setuptools from `/opt/symphony-client`, which seems odd. Is `/opt/symphony-client` part of your PYTHONPATH?

Comment: Verify you do have the file `/opt/symphony-client/setuptools/msvc.py`. If you don't — the installation of `setuptools` is broken and you should try to repair or upgrade it.